# Remap Dell L502X touch keys on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard, dell, xps, shortcut-keys, remapping

I have a Dell XPS L502X which has 3 touch keys. [Touch keys (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVxbn.jpg)

In Windows, the first one is supposed to bring up Windows Mobility Center or on newer versions, Windows + X. The second is programmable. The third is supposed to bring up volume settings (Realtek Audio Manager).

There are many posts on the internet about how to do this with \lib\udev\keymap, but in 16.04 this does not exist. How can I remap these keys in Ubuntu 16.04?

### evtest output

#### first key

```
Event: time 1465751670.091739, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value db
Event: time 1465751670.091739, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 1
Event: time 1465751670.091739, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1465751670.092485, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 2d
Event: time 1465751670.092485, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 45 (KEY_X), value 1
Event: time 1465751670.092485, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1465751670.094599, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 2d
Event: time 1465751670.094599, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 45 (KEY_X), value 0
Event: time 1465751670.094599, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1465751670.098470, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value db
Event: time 1465751670.098470, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 0
Event: time 1465751670.098470, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

#### second key

```
Event: time 1465751794.612427, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 85
Event: time 1465751794.612427, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN), value 1
Event: time 1465751794.612427, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1465751794.612512, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 85
Event: time 1465751794.612512, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN), value 0
Event: time 1465751794.612512, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

#### third key

```
Event: time 1465752067.641516, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 84
Event: time 1465752067.641516, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG), value 1
Event: time 1465752067.641516, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1465752067.644638, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 84
Event: time 1465752067.644638, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG), value 0
Event: time 1465752067.644638, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest is the below.

1. Open keyboard settings (System Settings-->Keyboard)
2. Click on the shortcut tab and using the left navigator pane try to identify whether there is a shortcut that does what you're looking for.
3. If there's not, click on the plus symbol at the bottom of the window.
4. Enter an identifiable name for the shortcut.
5. Type in the command (as you would in terminal) to access the program you want to open and click apply.
6. By default your shortcut will be disabled, click where it says disabled to change the text to set accelerator
7. Enter your shortcut as you normally would holding down the dominant key first i.e. ctrl or alt. or the exact key if no dominant key is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, even though the selected shortcut (lock) is set to Monitor brightness down (default action of the second touch key), it continues to lower the brightness. On the third touch key, it works, but the Fn command for next track (default action of the third touch key) locks the screen instead. The first touch key is fine.

Comment: Ok, the only thing I can suggest then would be to install and configure key-touch Editor. It can be a bit complicated, but I'm sure it will do as planned.
http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/dl-keytouch-editor.php

Comment: Unfortunately my key-touch Editor file will not open in KeyTouch.

Comment: @DhinakG Hey did you ever find a solution to this. I've been trying to remap my keys as well. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @IsabelInc, but it doesn't seem like there is a solution to this.

Comment: @DhinakG I've been trying to figure this out and for some reason it seems the keys are generating the same key code as some other keys. (Even though they are physically different keys). I wonder if it's a bug with the kernel and HW interface.